# Ordenar en pantalla una consulta MYSQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

tengo una consulta Mysql que parece me devuelve los resultados esperados....estoy intentando colocalos en una tabla html de forma que los elementos sean las columnas y los trabajadores las filas....

Conoceis alguna forma sencilla de hacerlo..???

```
SELECT 
  `docepi`.`elemento`,
  SUM(`docepi`.`cantidad`) AS `Cantidad`,
  `epi`.`fecha`,
  `trabajadores`.`Nombre`
FROM
  `trabajadores`
  INNER JOIN `epi` ON (`trabajadores`.`id` = `epi`.`usuario`)
  INNER JOIN `docepi` ON (`trabajadores`.`id` = `docepi`.`usuario`)
GROUP BY
  `docepi`.`elemento`,
  `epi`.`fecha`,
  `trabajadores`.`Nombre`
```

sería algo como:

|  | Elemento1 | Elemento2 | Elemento3 | Elemento4 | Elemento5 | Elemento6 | Elemento7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Trabajador 1 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Trabajador 2 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Trabajador 3 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

a ver si me explico mejor:
La consulta me devuelve esto:

```
elemento      cantidad       Trabajador
   1              3           Antonio
   1              2           Felipe
   3              1           Antonio
```

lo que quiero es presentar estos datos en una tabla html de esta forma:

```
          Elemento1  Elemento3  Elemento3  Elemento......
Antonio       3                      1
Felipe        2
....
.....
```

En PHP Puedo hacerlo, a la antigua usanza, a base de bucles, comparaciones y sería muy laborioso de hacer y si hay alguna modificación echate a temblar....
Seguro que conoceis alguna forma mas sencilla y elegante de hacerlo

Como Siempre.. Gracias..Chavales...

Comment: ¿No te sirve la clausura [ORDER BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/order-by-optimization.html) de MySQL?

Comment: No queda del todo clara la pregunta. Lo que estás diciendo es que tienes los datos que quieres en MySQL y solo necesitas pasarlos HTML? O hay algo adicional que quieres hacer con esos datos antes de pasarlos a una tabla? Estoy asumiendo que la consulta de MySQL ya te devuelve una fila por cada trabajador.

Comment: Creo que deberías indicarnos si deseas que los datos aparezcan formateados en un HTML, por que según tu consulta en MySQL los datos se muestran de manera correcta, y de ser así lo que requieres es un datatable de jquery o un jqGrid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según entiendo lo que tu quieres hacer es transponer la query (que aparezcan los elementos como columnas).

Una forma de hacerlo en MySql es utilizar la declaración (statment) `CASE`, el problema es que necesitarás un `CASE` por cada elemento distinto. Por lo que por ahí te conviene hacerlo directamente en php (sobre todo si tienes muchos elementos).

En este caso al agrupar por fecha y trabajador un mismo trabador podrá aparecer varias veces (en distintas fechas), aclaro esto porque no veo la columna fecha en tu salida espearda en la pregunta.

Saqué del `GROUP BY` la columna 'elemento'.

Puedes agregar el `ELSE 0` en los `CASE` para que te muestre cero en lugar de `null` cuando no haya cantidades para un determinado elemento en una fecha y para un determinado trabajador.

```
SELECT 
  `epi`.`fecha`,
  `trabajadores`.`Nombre`,
   SUM(CASE WHEN `docepi`.`elemento` = 'Elemento1' THEN `docepi`.`cantidad` END) AS elemento1,
   .
   .
   .
   SUM(CASE WHEN `docepi`.`elemento` = 'ElementoN' THEN `docepi`.`cantidad` END) AS elementoN

FROM `trabajadores`
INNER JOIN `epi` ON `trabajadores`.`id` = `epi`.`usuario`
INNER JOIN `docepi` ON `trabajadores`.`id` = `docepi`.`usuario`
GROUP BY `epi`.`fecha`, `trabajadores`.`Nombre`;
```

#### ACTUALIZADA

Según el ejemplo que agregaste en la pregunta, en el resultado no aparece la columna fecha (por lo tanto la quito de mi query), además parece que la columna "elemento" es de tipo entero (en mi query utilizo N como el mayor entero de la columna elemento). Actualizo la query en función de tu ejemplo:

```
SELECT 
  `trabajadores`.`Nombre` AS Trabajador,
   SUM(CASE WHEN `docepi`.`elemento` = 1 THEN `docepi`.`cantidad` END) AS elemento1,
   .
   .
   .
   SUM(CASE WHEN `docepi`.`elemento` = N THEN `docepi`.`cantidad` END) AS elementoN

FROM `trabajadores`
INNER JOIN `epi` ON `trabajadores`.`id` = `epi`.`usuario`
INNER JOIN `docepi` ON `trabajadores`.`id` = `docepi`.`usuario`
GROUP BY `trabajadores`.`Nombre`;
```

##### Query dinámica:

Con esta query creamos la query anterior.

```
(SELECT 'SELECT ')

UNION ALL

(SELECT 
    concat('SUM(CASE WHEN docepi.elemento = ', elemento, ' THEN docepi.cantidad ELSE 0 END) AS elemento', elemento, ',')
FROM docepi
GROUP BY elemento)

UNION ALL

(SELECT 'trabajadores.Nombre AS Trabajador
         FROM trabajadores
         INNER JOIN epi ON trabajadores.id = epi.usuario
         INNER JOIN docepi ON trabajadores.id = docepi.usuario
         GROUP BY trabajadores.Nombre;')
```

La salida sería (para el ejemplo utilicé los siguientes valores para la columna elemento: 1, 2, 3 y 4; por eso son 4 los `CASE`):

| Query dinámica |
| --- |
| SELECT |
| SUM(CASE WHEN docepi.elemento = 1 THEN docepi.cantidad ELSE 0 END) AS elemento1, |
| SUM(CASE WHEN docepi.elemento = 2 THEN docepi.cantidad ELSE 0 END) AS elemento2, |
| SUM(CASE WHEN docepi.elemento = 3 THEN docepi.cantidad ELSE 0 END) AS elemento3, |
| SUM(CASE WHEN docepi.elemento = 4 THEN docepi.cantidad ELSE 0 END) AS elemento4, |
| trabajadores.Nombre AS Trabajador FROM trabajadores INNER JOIN epi ON trabajadores.id = epi.usuario INNER JOIN docepi ON trabajadores.id = docepi.usuario GROUP BY trabajadores.Nombre; |

El resultado es la query que buscas vos. También podés hacer algo parecido con php.

Es posible que haya que retocar la query dinámica, porque como no cuento con tu modelo de datos, no la he podido probar.

Comment: Gracias, El numero de elementos es variable, el usuario puede agregar más elementos, y habría que modificar la consulta....

Comment: De nada @Aldeano! En ese caso podrías generar la query dinamicamente, ya sea utilizando un lenguaje de programación o utilizando sql (usas una query para generar la query que escribí yo).

Comment: creo entender la propuesta, pero trato de probarla en mysql y dice esto: #1054 - La columna 'elemento' en field list es desconocida

Comment: Recién modifiqué la query, porque para probarla yo creé la columna elemento en la tabla trabajadores (no creé todas las tablas), y me había quedado así, es posible que sea ese el problema.

Comment: ya está resuelto, no te preocupes...ya te contaré...

Answer (score 0):

Si ya tienes los datos por medio de la consulta solo debes cargar la tabla en HTML con estos a tu conveniencia, en este caso elementos como columnas y trabajadores como filas. Acá te dejo el link de la W3Schools para tablas en HTML: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp.